# are adhoc queries/updates starting to kill your productivity with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

i've been developing a asp mvc website for almost a year now exclusively on mongodb.  i've loved it for the most part.  development productivity has been great using a C# mongodb driver and tools like mongovue.

however, i've started to reach a point where there are things i really wish i had a SQL server database for.  simple tasks like updating a record in the DB and only mildly complex queries to generate some type of report are becoming a pain.

i read an article somewhere that in order for NOSSQL to succeed there needs to be a standard query language for it, and tools developed around it.  i'm guessing this is far far away, so right now i'm stuck trying to deal with these things.

i think eventually i will have to have a dual solution with monogDB and sql server.  i don't think i will ever get to the point where i am as productive updating and writing queries for mongoDB as i was with sql server.

how are you guys dealing with this when using NOSQL like mongodb?  are you facing the same issues as me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution you may consider is [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). You can set up a template with a reference to 10Gen's drivers and write ad-hoc, C# MongoDB queries like you would in your code. My team and I use this method to address the very problem you mention.

Try it out (it's free) and see if it can help with the simple, day-to-day queries you come up with.

*Edit* I also support Chris's suggestion of familiarizing yourself with the native JSON query language. Nothing beats a quick console window for speed, if you know the syntax.

Comment: Love LINQPad, this is a brilliant idea.

Comment: i actually use (and love) linqpad, but didn't think of using it this way!

Answer (score 1):

The official C# driver will probably get a LINQ provider some time in the future, so that'd give .NET devs a familiar syntax for querying and maybe help with initial productivity.  There're also some nice docs that help relate MongoDB queries back to SQL:

- [SQL to Mongo Mapping Chart](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart)
- [SQL to MongoDB (PDF)](http://rickosborne.org/download/SQL-to-MongoDB.pdf)

These are great for learning, but to get the most out of Mongo it's well worth investing time getting used to the native JSON query syntax and Mongo-specific concepts like map-reduce.

Comment: i had not seen those mapping files until now. excellent resource and should come in very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Since your questions asks,

> how are you guys dealing with this when using NOSQL *like* mongodb?

I thought I'd chime in. I felt your pain when working with another NOSQL database, RavenDB.

I wrote a Linqpad driver specifically for ad hoc interactions with RavenDB.

https://github.com/ronnieoverby/RavenDB-Linqpad-Driver